# case class with var Enum member, value is not saved after exiting scope

Tags: scala, enums, scala-2.10

I am missing something over here.

I have a case class that contains some string members and 2 enums.
class constructor receive the enum values as string.

I use the command:

```
var order = Order.withName(orderInput) //Order is an object that extends Enumeration
```

In order to avoid exception on class construction (if the input string is not in the enum values, I set  the enum value upon construction of the class to a default value.

I have a validation function for this case class, during validation i set the enum, this case if i get exception, its during validation and not while constructing the object.

The code looks like:

Enum code:

```
object Order extends Enumeration {
  type OrderType = Value
  val asc = Value("asc")
  val desc = Value("desc")

  def validateOrder(orderInput:String)
  {
      val orderValidate = Order.isOrderType(orderInput)
      if (!orderValidate)
        throw new Exception("Order is invalid ("+orderInput+")!")       
  }
  def isOrderType(s: String) = values.find(_.toString.equals(s)).isDefined
}
```

My Case Class:

```
case class ProductsByCategoriesRequest(langaugeInput:String, tenantIdInput:String, categoriesIds:List[String], startInput:Integer, maxResultsInput:Integer,sortInput:String,orderInput: String)
extends ProductSorting 
with Paging
with LanguageFilter
with TenantFilter
 with BaseRequest
{
  var order = Order.asc //default value
  var sortField = Field.name //default value
  val maxResults = maxResultsInput
  val start = startInput
  val language = langaugeInput
  val tenantId = tenantIdInput

  def validate()
  {

    if (StringUtils.isListNullOrEmpty(categoriesIds))
      throw new Exception("Categories Ids list is invalid")    
     validateLanguage
     validateTenant
     Order.validateOrder(orderInput)
     var order = Order.withName(orderInput)
     Field.validateField(sortInput)
     var sortField = Field.withName(sortInput)     
  }
}
```

What is weird ?  During validation the enum is changed, but later on when i use this object, and getting the value of the enum, it will always be "asc" as the default. although i set it as "desc" and saw it changes!

This probably has something to do with objects behavior in scala and the fact that var does not keep the true status of the member after existing the scope maybe ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining *new* variables (with narrower scope) named order and sortField in `validate` instead of assigning the values to the previously declared vars - remove the `var` from the `order` and `sortField` assignments there.

So:

```
var order = Order.withName(orderInput)
Field.validateField(sortInput)
var sortField = Field.withName(sortInput)
```

Should become:

```
order = Order.withName(orderInput)
Field.validateField(sortInput)
sortField = Field.withName(sortInput)
```

Comment: Thanks, this what happens after alot of coding hours :)